# test class for a controller

Tags: unit-test, class

```
public class AccountNumber {
    public static string r;
    public list<Customer_Details__c> ds;
    public static void UpdatingAccountNumber(list<Customer_Details__c> ds) {
        for(Customer_Details__c p :ds) {
            ds=new list<Customer_Details__c>();
            Customer_Details__c pay=[select Account_Number__c from Customer_Details__c where id=:p.id];
            string s=p.Branch_Name__c.SubString(0,3);
            string naming=p.Customer_Name__c;
            string last3;
            if (naming.length() < 3) {
                last3 = naming;
            } else {
                last3 = naming.substring(naming.length() - 3);
            }
            //string name3=p.Customer_Name__c.SubString(0,3);
            //string r;
            r=p.Name;
            Integer l=0;
            l=r.length();
            String numbers = r.substring(l - 4);
            string total=p.Branch_Id__c+s+last3 +numbers ;
            string gtotal=total.trim();
            pay.Account_Number__c =total ;
            update pay;
        }
    }

    public static void SendErrorMessage(list<Customer_Details__c> err){
        system.debug('entering err'+err);
        //list<Customer_Details__c> custD=trigger.new;
        for(Customer_Details__c ccd:err){
            system.debug('enrter--------'+ccd.Transaction_Type__c);
            if(ccd.Transaction_Type__c=='Withdraw'){
                system.debug('customerdetailing'+ccd.Total_Amount__c);
                if(ccd.Total_Amount__c < ccd.Initial_Amount__c){
                    ccd.addError('please provide validate Amount availabnle in ');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is my controller class,Iam trying to write test class for this controller like bellow,it is giving 54% code coverage.can u pls suggest me how to improve my code coverage.

```
@isTest
public class AccountNumberTest
{
    static testMethod void testMethod1() {
        Customer_Details__c  nwcusd=new Customer_Details__c ();

        nwcusd.Branch_Id__c='001';
        nwcusd.Branch_Name__c='hyderabssd';
        nwcusd.Customer_Name__c='new bui.l';
        nwcusd.Initial_Amount__c=100;
        nwcusd.Total_Amount__c=600;
        nwcusd.Transaction_Amount__c=0;
        nwcusd.Transaction_Type__c='New Account';
        nwcusd.Account_Number__c=(nwcusd.Branch_Id__c.SubString(0,3)+' '+nwcusd.Branch_Name__c.SubString(0,3)+' '+nwcusd.Customer_Name__c.SubString(0,3)+'20160346'.substring(8 -4)).trim();
        integer l=8;
        insert nwcusd;
        string settt=nwcusd.Name;
        list<Customer_Details__c> ds=new list<Customer_Details__c>();

        ds.add(nwcusd);
        //AccountNumber nedfr=new AccountNumber();
        //nedfr.name='20160346';
        AccountNumber.UpdatingAccountNumber(ds);
    }
}
```

Comment: what are the lines that are not covered? You should try to find that first and then the reason for same or ask for a specific line which is not getting covered even though you have added proper test methods

Comment: `ds=new list<Customer_Details__c>();` isn't going to do what you want because  you have declared `ds` as an instance variable, not a static variable

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 public methods in the class you want to cover, so you would have to create 2 tests, one calling each of your methods.

Also, the second method has 2 nested if's. If you want maximum coverage, try to create a `list<Customer_Details__c>` with at least 1 `Customer_Details__c` that matches the 2 nested if's (transaction type = withdraw and ccd.Total_Amount__c < ccd.Initial_Amount__c).

That should do it.